# Error bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent types: Float32 and Float64

Tags: google-earth-engine, integer

I have an image that I have created which is basically paired image with two bands: 
band 1 is NDVI image from Sentinel 2
band 2 is SAR image from Sentinel 1

I have tried to export this image to my drive and I get the next error:

> bands must have compatible data types; found inconsistent types:
>   Float32 and Float64.

I have seen here few posts about the same error, but couldn't fix it:

I have tried to change it to int16, and it worked, but i'm afraid I'm losing data. I have tried to use the same code but instead of 16 to put 32 but i'm afraid I'm losing data from the 64 and to be honest I couldn't understand really the different between the different numbers. Also, I couldn't use toUint64().
When I upload the int32 image to QGIS, I got black square with values of 0. I don't really need the visualization but I'm worried that I have gotten values 0 and I don't have any value.

```
pairedImage = pairedImage.toUint32();

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: pairedImage,
  description: 'imageToDriveExample',
  scale: 20,
  region: geometry
});
print('Paired Image',pairedImage);
```

My end goal is to understand what are the consequence of this, which data I might lose and how I can keep my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sentinel-1 SAR bands are Double type (64-bit floating point) and
computed images derived from `normalizedDifference()` (e.g., NDVI) are Float type (32-bit floating point).

The difference is in range capacity and precision. However, regarding satellite-based image data, the full capacity of 32-bit floating point precision is far more precision than the instruments can provide, so using the lowest precision data type of your images (Float) would be fine. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985) for more information on Float and Double types.

When you cast floating point data using `toUint32()` you are eliminating the unit fraction and forcing negative values to 0, which is why your result is all 0s.

I would cast both bands to Float independently and then combine them for exporting.

```js
// Cast SAR band to 32-bit floating point.
mySarBand = mySarBand.toFloat();

// Cast NDVI band to 32-bit floating point.
myNdviBand = myNdviBand.toFloat();

// Combine the bands into a single image.
var pairedImage = ee.Image.cat([mySarBand, myNdviBand])
  .rename('SAR', 'NDVI');

// Export image to Drive.
Export.image.toDrive({...arguments...});
```

Depending on the range of the data, you can also minimize file size by multiplying your data by 1,000 or 10,000 and then cast as `Int16`, which retains a few decimal places of precision for floating point data, which is generally enough.

```js
var myDataScaled = myData.multiply(10000).toShort();
```